# How does one set a dedicated IP address to a minecraft server on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: ip, ip-address, dedicated-server, gameserver

So I bought a dedicated server from staminus.net just for running a Minecraft server. On Minecraft, the default port is 25565. I am wondering how one makes it so that there is no port on the IP address for the Minecraft server. The reason I don't want a port is because I want to make an A Name record from my domain to the IP, as number IP addresses are hard to remember. Thanks!

BTW, the dedicated server has two static IP addresses. Thanks!

Comment: This is off-topic per our [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq), as it does not pertain to professional computer administration. [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit.

Comment: He's looking to forward all traffic that reaches an IP to a socket. It's network related. The question could be worded better though.

Comment: It's still dubious that this passes the "in a professional capacity" test. Purchasing a dedicated gaming server without an understanding of some very basic industry principles places this close to being in a home setting. In either case, one is far more likely to get enthusiastic support from the dedicated server operators in [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft will automatically use the default port to connect to a server if there is no port specified in the server IP address when you connect to it. Simply make sure that your server uses the default port and that your A-Record points to your dedicated server's main IP.

Also, make sure that Windows firewall is configured to accept connections on port `25565` on all IP addresses.

Comment: Well, my question is how to get rid of the port entirely, and just have the dedicated IP route to the minecraft server. Thanks!

Comment: Like I said, as long as you use the default port, if you put the dedicated IP on the minecraft client without the port it will go to the correct port. If what you're looking to do is redirect all traffic to the dedicated IP to the minecraft socket I do not believe that's possible.